# Python Scikit-learn CountVectorizer throwing ValueError: empty vocabulary

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, vectorization, feature-extraction, text-analysis

I'm trying to extract features from a text document. Here is my code:

`import sklearn`
`from sklearn.datasets import load_files`
`from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer`
`files = sklearn.datasets.load_files('/home/niyas/Documents/project/container', shuffle = False)`
`vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=1)`
`X = vectorizer.fit_transform(files.data[1])`
`Y=vectorizer.get_feature_names()`

I'm getting an error "ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words". The code works fine when I pass a string with the exact same content of the text doc.

Help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't it just be ``files.data``? can you give the content of ``files.data[0]``?

Comment: Actually I can print `files.data[1]` and the above code works fine when I pass a string with the exact same content of the text doc.

Comment: I know you can print, ``files.data[1]``, I was asking what it contains. Which text doc? The one that is found by ``load_files`` as ``files.data[1]``?

Comment: Here is the complete text.   "Acer S1213Hne 3D Ready DLP Projector - 720p - HDTV - 4:3 - 2.6 - NTSC, PAL, SECAM - 1024 x 768 - XGA - 17,000:1 - 3000 lm - HDMI - USB - VGA In - Ethernet - 290 W - White Color - 1 Year WarrantyThe professional Acer P7 Series employs advanced technologies and convenient setup utilities to deliver clear, persuasive presentations in large business venues. Enterprising innovators like you will appreciate the high resolution, brightness and contrast ratio to drive your ventures toward greater success."

Comment: yeah so it is only a single string. It needs to be a list of strings, so either `` vectorizer.fit_transform([files.data[1]])`` or use all files: ``vectorizer.fit_transform(files.data)``.